# Temenos TAFJ subroutines - Location of Insert Files

Tags: jbase

While writing TAFJ subroutines, I am using the T24 Insert files.

I am looking for the location of the insert files like I_COMMON, I_EQUATE, I_F.CUSTOMER, etc.
So that I can use more of the common variables.

When I compile a TAFJ subroutine, I see the path below

Insert Source Dir.      = /apps/t24cldenv/bnk/t24lib

but there are only jar files in that directory, does anyone know where the insert files are located?

Answer (score 1):

The T24 Insert files are located inside the *.jar libraries in .../bnk/t24lib. Jar files are just ZIP files and when you unzip them, you will find the Insert files you need.

For example, I_F.CUSTOMER is located inside:
.../bnk/t24lib/ST_Customer.jar/INSERTS/I_F.CUSTOMER

I_COMMON inside:
.../bnk/t24lib/EB_SystemTables.jar/INSERTS/I_COMMON

You can search these jar archives using tools like Total Commander to find the file you need.

Comment: Thank you. I found those global variables. However, do you know where is the description of those? for example I_COMMON.

Comment: There is a file called I_RULES in t24lib\EB_RulesEngine.jar\INSERTS\ which describes a lot of the common variables defined in I_COMMON. For the rest, I don't think there is a single place where all of them are described - this is Temenos internal info that you can only find out from their source code.